# \twocolumn creates new page

Tags: supertabular

I am trying to use a supertabular in twocolumn mode.
The `\twocolumn` command creates a page break just after the section. How do I prevent that?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{siunitx}%
\usepackage{gensymb}%
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}%
\usepackage[margin=30mm,headsep=20mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{siunitx}%
\usepackage{tabu}%
\usepackage{supertabular}
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=50mm,keepaspectratio=true]{logo}}%
\rhead{Körinstruktion: 1001}%
\cfoot{\today}%
\DeclareSIUnit\rpm{rpm}%
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}%
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}%
%
\begin{document}%
\section*{TEST}%
\twocolumn
\begin{supertabular}{l l}%
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
  \textbf{Label} & Value \\
\end{supertabular}%
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Tried this, but it does not split the table rows in two columns

```
\begin{document}%
\section*{TEST}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \twocolumn
  \begin{supertabular}{l l}%
    \textbf{Label} & Value \\
    ...
  \end{supertabular}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, you can't. This is pretty much all `\twocolumn` does. Start a new page, start two columns.

Comment: You probably want to minimapges. Or two columns and the section title in one column?

Comment: I am creating these pages using pylatex. I want to split the table rows into two columns to save vertical space.
I will give minipages a try

Comment: Nope... The table wont split when wrapping in a minipage. Tried setting its width to both \textwidth and \linewidth

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: in this case put `\twocolumn` before the section or use the `[twocolumn]` documentclass option, if you can't do that in your full document give more context.

Comment: @Seamus was there anything else besides the inline code formatting you felt I missed?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Putting it as an option in documentclass did it. Make it an answer if you want the karma.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the *before the section* saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the whole document to be twocolumn it is better yo use the `[twocolumn]` documentclass option.